# Accessing custom attribute defined in a style

Tags: android, xamarin.android

The problem I am trying to solve is to have a custom font in an android application. I have followed a few tutorials and stack overflow questions but I can't seem to get exactly what I want.

I have a custom attribute defined in attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
    <attr name="customTypeface" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

and that customTypeface defined in the style:

```
<style name="posTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/posThemeTextViewStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="posThemeTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
        <item name="customTypeface">Fonts/MuseoSans_100.otf</item>
    </style>
```

in an activity the form looks looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="LOL OL U MAD BRO!"
                        />

    <myApplication.Controls.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="LOL OL U MAD BRO!"
                        ></myApplication.Controls.iQTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and when I go about trying to get the attribute:

```
public CustomTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
            : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
           var a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    Resource.Styleable.CustomTextView);
            var customFont = a.GetString(Resource.Styleable.CustomTextView_customTypeface);
            SetCustomFont(customFont);
            a.Recycle();
        }
```

customFont is null, unless I implicitly define custom:customTypeface="" in the activity but I don't want to have to define the font for every single instance of the control.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't those two lines :

```
var a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                Resource.Styleable.CustomTextView);
        var customFont = a.GetString(Resource.Styleable.CustomTextView_customTypeface);
```

be :

```
var a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.Styleable.CustomTextView);
        var customFont = a.GetString(R.Styleable.CustomTextView_customTypeface);
```

Comment: Its monodroid, which uses Resource instead of 'R'.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that. Did you have any luck? Why the starting tag is : myApplication.Controls.CustomTextView and the ending tag :
myApplication.Controls.iQTextView ? could this be the problem ?Unless it's also a monodroid thing.